# environment variables are undefined in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an application utilizing the spotify API. I have secrets I want to keep in the form of Client ID's , endpoints and the like. I've done everything I am required to do to successfully use environment variables in react. This includes prefixing my variables with REACT_APP_ and making sure .env is in the root folder. In the code shown below, I am able to briefly console.log my environment variables.

```
 const login = useRef(`${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${process.env.REACT_APP_RESPONSE_TYPE}`);
```

yet when I try to access them in a render here it is undefined

```
{!token ?

            <a href={login.current}>Login to spotify</a>
            :
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout </button>

          }
          {
            token ?

              <form onSubmit={searchArtists}>
                <input type='text' onChange={e => setSearchKey(e.target.value)} placeholder='search for a song or artist' />
                <button type='{submit}'>Search</button>
              </form>
              
              :
              <h2>Please login</h2>
          }
}
```

I made sure to use a useRef hook just to make sure that the values persist so I can use my secrets when I want to return a render for react. This was to no avail.
I have a feeling it has to do with when I refresh? or perhaps my environment clears after I go to my redirect URI?
I also didn't bother importing dotenv because from what I've read , React handles all of that on its own.
For reference here is the .env file as well:

```
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID =*************************
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI =https://swipewithspotify.vercel.app/
REACT_APP_AUTH_ENDPOINT =https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
REACT_APP_RESPONSE_TYPE =token
```

If there's some concept that I have wrong I'd love an explanation if possible or any kind of light to be sure shed on this problem.

Comment: Have you restarted your app? Whenever you add or change env variables you have to restart

Comment: I've restarted it every time I've changed something. Plus It's a react app anyways so it restarts on save I believe. @RichardHpa

Comment: Get rid of the spaces before the `=` signs in your `.env` file

Comment: Got rid of the spaces. seems this didn't have an effect on the presence of the environment variables when I want to use them in a render. But I appreciate that it is proper .env syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to Add env variable if we got undefined type error, I solved the same problem. Please follow these steps.

1. **npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev**
2. Create .env file under root folder
   3.create env variable as

```
REACT_APP_MY_API=342432...
```

4. Create **webpack.config.js** file under the root folder with the following content
5. add this same code into **webpack.config.js** file.

   ```
    const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
     module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv()
      ]
    }
   ```
6. And you can use where do you want in your root folder or src folder
7. access variables like this

```
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API;
```

8. When you add a variable into env file and still got undefined make sure you restart your server